# Caching in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Please provide me an example for caching a webpage in codeigniter. The View page is going to be the same always., i.e., Static View page.
It takes very long time to load a webpage that is often used.

Comment: We'll need some more info about the pages that are slow. eg code samples

Comment: Please provide me an candybar. SO is not for asking things. You have to search for it yourself. If you´re stuck on something you could ask here for help.

Comment: Have you tried their site: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html

Comment: Is your page truly static? Then I don't see why it takes long time to load.

Answer (score 1):

please put htaccess file in the folder and write :

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
```

now please put this htaccess file in folder which file you want to make cache.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the view you can add

```
$this->output->cache(n);
```

> Where n is the number of minutes you wish the page to remain cached
>   between refreshes.